# Does Shepherds/Ambassadors give me gold when I build by moving a settlement?

Tags: kingdom-builder

The *Nomads* expansion has a Shepherds Ambassadors Kingdom Builder cards, which give you gold during the game for building in certain places (solo terrain hexes and next to other players, respectively). **Do you get gold by *moving* a settlement into a qualifying hex** via locations like Paddock and Caravan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say no. *Moving* a settlement is not *building* it.

The rules say:

> The active player must check whether the conditions on red cards have been met **after building each single new settlement**. If these conditions have been fulfilled, the player immediately records the gold earned on the score track.

This interpretation is confirmed by the BoardGameGeek’s FAQs [Shepherds only gives points for built, not moved, settlements](http://boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/Kingdom_Builder%3A_Nomads_FAQ#toc13) and [Ambassadors only give points for built, not moved, settlements](http://boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/Kingdom_Builder%3A_Nomads_FAQ#toc15). Both reference the thread [Questions on rules](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/797783/questions-rules), in which Kingdom Builder’s game designer Donald X. [answered](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/9068478#9068478):

> No. Shepherds and Ambassadors do not score for moved pieces.